# IE -7/8, event-target not working

Tags: internet-explorer

I am developing a use case in which some action needs to be taken once the user checks/unchecks a checkbox.

Example:

Function snippet:

```
<script>
function toggleAgreement(event) {
if(event.target == 'some pre-defined ID') {
//do action;
}
</script>
```

Problem:

This function is working well in Firefox/Chrome, even in IE9 it's working. Just in IE-7/8, it doesn't work.

On observing the IE script console, these errors are shown on --> bodyOnload (not when i trigger this particular checkbox).

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'"
>   iframe.html, line x character y

When clicking this link, I get to see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

I researched and found out the way Jquery that should be used is:
`"document.querySelectorAll('.className')"`

The thing is, even if this problem prevails in IE9, why doesn't it throw the above mentioned error?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.target is not compatible with IE.  Try this instead (it's cross-browser compatible):

```
<script>
    function toggleAgreement(event) {
        var evt = e || window.event; // this assigns evt with the event object
        var current = evt.target || evt.srcElement; // this assigns current with the event target
        if(current == 'some pre-defined ID') {
            //do action;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? It makes working with events much easier (essential to take 1.x version for early IE version support). With jQuery it's as easy as:

```
$("#myCheckbox").click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     // Do whatever you want
   }
});
```

No need to use "event target" anymore, the clicked checkbox is available in the provided "$(this)" object. But it's [available](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), if you need to.